# I am unable to install mlrose package

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pip

Whenever I pip install mlrose, it is showing me the following error. I am new to machine learning, so a detailed explaination will be appreciated.

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.1069]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\admin>pip install mlrose

```
Collecting mlrose
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0d/f8/79e77a40f6e8988e3ecc9ead8a28024ee43df9c99fce2209037c9e6f9e4a/mlrose-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from mlrose) (1.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from mlrose) (1.17.4)
Processing c:\users\admin\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\76\03\bb\589d421d27431bcd2c6da284d5f2286c8e3b2ea3cf1594c074\sklearn-0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1e/ce/9d8c88e68af0a5b5c5d78d8d2b7bcadfd45e1d6afc863ccb9aee30765b06/scikit-learn-0.21.3.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn->sklearn->mlrose) (0.14.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: scikit-learn
  Building wheel for scikit-learn (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-install-8ooeas1k\\scikit-learn\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-install-8ooeas1k\\scikit-learn\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-wheel-jm5hdzgz' --python-tag cp38
       cwd: C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-8ooeas1k\scikit-learn\
  Complete output (37 lines):
  Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-8ooeas1k\scikit-learn\setup.py", line 290, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-8ooeas1k\scikit-learn\setup.py", line 286, in setup_package
      setup(**metadata)
    File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 137, in setup
      config = configuration()
    File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-8ooeas1k\scikit-learn\setup.py", line 174, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage('sklearn')
    File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1033, in add_subpackage
      config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
    File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 999, in get_subpackage
      config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
    File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 941, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "sklearn\setup.py", line 76, in configuration
      maybe_cythonize_extensions(top_path, config)
    File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-8ooeas1k\scikit-learn\sklearn\_build_utils\__init__.py", line 42, in maybe_cythonize_extensions
      with_openmp = check_openmp_support()
    File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-8ooeas1k\scikit-learn\sklearn\_build_utils\openmp_helpers.py", line 83, in check_openmp_support
      ccompiler.compile(['test_openmp.c'], output_dir='objects',
    File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 360, in compile
      self.initialize()
    File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 253, in initialize
      vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
    File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 171, in msvc14_get_vc_env
      return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
    File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 1075, in __init__
      self.si = SystemInfo(self.ri, vc_ver)
    File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 547, in __init__
      vc_ver or self._find_latest_available_vs_ver())
    File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 561, in _find_latest_available_vs_ver
      raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(
  distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-learn
  Running setup.py clean for scikit-learn
Failed to build scikit-learn
Installing collected packages: scikit-learn, sklearn, mlrose
    Running setup.py install for scikit-learn ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-install-8ooeas1k\\scikit-learn\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-install-8ooeas1k\\scikit-learn\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-record-x04bx8yu\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-8ooeas1k\scikit-learn\
    Complete output (37 lines):
    Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-8ooeas1k\scikit-learn\setup.py", line 290, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-8ooeas1k\scikit-learn\setup.py", line 286, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 137, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-8ooeas1k\scikit-learn\setup.py", line 174, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('sklearn')
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1033, in add_subpackage
        config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 999, in get_subpackage
        config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 941, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "sklearn\setup.py", line 76, in configuration
        maybe_cythonize_extensions(top_path, config)
      File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-8ooeas1k\scikit-learn\sklearn\_build_utils\__init__.py", line 42, in maybe_cythonize_extensions
        with_openmp = check_openmp_support()
      File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-8ooeas1k\scikit-learn\sklearn\_build_utils\openmp_helpers.py", line 83, in check_openmp_support
        ccompiler.compile(['test_openmp.c'], output_dir='objects',
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 360, in compile
        self.initialize()
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 253, in initialize
        vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 171, in msvc14_get_vc_env
        return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 1075, in __init__
        self.si = SystemInfo(self.ri, vc_ver)
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 547, in __init__
        vc_ver or self._find_latest_available_vs_ver())
      File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 561, in _find_latest_available_vs_ver
        raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(
    distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-install-8ooeas1k\\scikit-learn\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-install-8ooeas1k\\scikit-learn\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-record-x04bx8yu\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

What do I do?

Comment: Have you tried installing the visual build tools? From your error: "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/"

Answer (score 1):

Your error says:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

What it is telling you is that you need to have `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0` installed on your machine in order to install your module. It is the standard toolchain to compile c/cpp source code for windows platforms. This is needed if you try to install a python module from source that has some parts written in c/cpp for speed that need to be compiled.

Getting an installation from source working for complicated modules can be a pain, esspecially on windows, but fortunately, you have Options:

---

Usually many well known packages provide `whl` files, which are pre-compiled versions of the module and can be readily installed without the need to compile anything on your Computer. In your case, you can see from the output, that `mlrose` is actually downloaded as a `whl` file

```
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0d/f8/79e77a40f6e8988e3ecc9ead8a28024ee43df9c99fce2209037c9e6f9e4a/mlrose-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

However `scikit-learn` (which is a dependency) is downloaded as source code, instead of a `whl` file:

```
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1e/ce/9d8c88e68af0a5b5c5d78d8d2b7bcadfd45e1d6afc863ccb9aee30765b06/scikit-learn-0.21.3.tar.gz
```

And during its compilation, the error pops up that you don't have the neccessary compiler installed. If you check the [pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/#files), you can see that for your python version (python 3.8) there are no whl files available, they only go up to `cp37` (=python 3.7).

Python 3.8 is rather new, therefore there are not always official pre-built whl files available. Now you could either:

1. Uninstall python 3.8 and instead install python 3.7 for which the chance is higher to habve official whl files on pypi
2. Use whl files from an unofficial source, i.e [this one](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn)
3. Uninstall python 3.8 and install python 3.7 using [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section) which comes with many packages pre installed
4. Install the Microsoft Visual Build Tools and try to compile the relevant libs yourself

My suggestion would be to go with #3 if you just want to have an installation running as quickly and worry free as possible and don't care if you have python 3.7 or python 3.8